# Select2 removes data on edit event in form

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2, phalcon

I'm trying to fetch the selected data in select 2 box and then allow the user to select other entries from drop down. But when a user click on EDIT the form loads all the data but in select2 drop down data is shown for a second and then it flushes/hides.

Video:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B10cFedD7h9o1MybhLlmlyq_voL7T6SP/view

Form JS:

```
// Init the Cx Form
    $cxRecordEditForm.cxForm({
        loadDataUrl: '<?php echo $this->CxHelper->Route('eb-admin-get-evaluation-cause-by-id')?>',
        loadData: {listSymptoms: true, listRemedies: true},
        loadSuccess: function(formData){
            if(formData){
                // Get Linked Symptoms on EDIT
                var symptomsListArray = formData.symptoms_list;
                if(symptomsListArray){
                    symptomsListArray.forEach(function(entry) {
                        // create the option and append to Select2
                        var option = new Option(entry.text, entry.id, true, true);
                        $('#symptoms_list').append(option).trigger('change');
                    });
                }

                // Get Linked Remedies on EDIT
                var remediesListArray = formData.remedies_list;
                if(remediesListArray){
                    remediesListArray.forEach(function(entry) {
                        // create the option and append to Select2
                        var option = new Option(entry.text, entry.id, true, true);
                        $('#remedies_list').append(option).trigger('change');
                    });
                }
            }
        },
```

View:

```
<section class="col col-6">
                                                <label class="label">{{EbEvaluationCauseForm.getLabel("symptoms_list")}}</label>
                                                <label class="input">
                                                    {{ EbEvaluationCauseForm.render("symptoms_list", ["class": "select2"]) }}
                                                </label>
                                            </section>

                                            <section class="col col-6">
                                                <label class="label">{{EbEvaluationCauseForm.getLabel("remedies_list")}}</label>
                                                <label class="input">
                                                    {{ EbEvaluationCauseForm.render("remedies_list", ["class": "select2"]) }}
                                                </label>
                                            </section>
```

Form:

```
public function initialize() {

        // Create form fields
        $this->add($this->createHiddenField('id'));
        $this->add($this->createTextField('title', 'Title', false));
        $this->add($this->createTextField('description', 'Explanation', false));
        $this->add($this->createSelect2Field('symptoms_list', 'Symptoms', 'Select Symptom','symptoms',false, true, true));
        $this->add($this->createSelect2Field('remedies_list', 'Remedies', 'Select Remedy','remedies',false, true, true));
    }
```

JSON return on EDIT click is:

> {"data":{"id":53,"title":"Well Test","description":"Well Test
>   explained","is_active":1,"order_by":null,"date_created":"0000-00-00
>   00:00:00","date_updated":"0000-00-00
>   00:00:00","symptoms":[{"id":18,"text":"Calf
>   tenderness"}],"symptoms_list":[{"id":18,"text":"Calf
>   tenderness"}],"remedies":[{"id":4,"text":"Adrenal
>   Kit"},{"id":4,"text":"Adrenal
>   Kit"}],"remedies_list":[{"id":4,"text":"Adrenal
>   Kit"},{"id":4,"text":"Adrenal Kit"}]}}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the controller is regenerating the view, have you tried:

```
$this->view->disable();
```

with it?